# Net::HTTPでNet::OpenTimeout (execution expired)に対処したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aws

#### 前提

現在Ruby on Railsを用いてGoogle Books ApiにGETリクエストを送りresponseを加工してNuxt.jsにJsonデータを返却する機能を作っています。

Railsの中で以下のmodelに定義したメソッドを使用してGoogle Books ApiにGETリクエストを送る機能を作りました。
ローカル環境では正常に作動しているのですが、
aws(ecs、EC2)にデプロイしたところ表題の通りエラーが発生しました。

数日詰まっているため、皆様の知恵を貸していただきたくて質問しました。

追記
こちらのサイトでも同様の質問を行っております。
解決した場合は双方のサイトにご報告し、私と同様の問題を抱える方の助けになるよう解決策をシェアいたします。
https://teratail.com/questions/dljdho1ts6d9ha

※９月４日～
上記サイトにて教えていただいた事や調査結果から「RailsのEc2コンテナからGoogleApiに対しgetリクエストが届かない(Ec2コンテナとGoogleApiとの疎通が取れていない)」という現状が把握が出来たため上記サイト側では解決済となっています。
しかし、「Net::HTTPでGoogle Books ApiにGETリクエストを送り、レスポンスを得たい」という目標は未達のため、調査を継続し、解決するまで補足情報に途中経過を記載しています。

#### 実現したいこと

●何が起きているか知りたい。
●Net::HTTPでNet::OpenTimeout (execution expired)に対処したい。

#### 発生している問題・エラーログ

●aws環境のログ

```
Started GET "/api/v1/books/search/?keyword=%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88" for 000.000.00.000 at 2022-09-03 16:11:58 +0900
Processing by Api::V1::BooksController#search as HTML
Parameters: {"keyword"=>"........."}
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=.........&country=JP
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88&country=JP
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88&country=JP
#<Net::HTTP:0x00007f7e4c5fd008>
#<Net::HTTP::Get:0x00007f7e4c5fcdb0>
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 60002ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 2006)
↓関係していそうなlogデータ
Net::OpenTimeout (execution expired):
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/http.rb:987:in `initialize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/http.rb:987:in `open'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/http.rb:987:in `block in connect'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/timeout.rb:107:in `timeout'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/http.rb:985:in `connect'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/http.rb:970:in `do_start'
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/http.rb:959:in `start'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/http.rb:1512:in `request'
↑関係していそうなlogデータ
/app/models/google_book.rb:61:in `search'
```

●ローカル環境のログ

```
Started GET "/api/v1/books/search/?keyword=%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88" for 000.00.0.0 at 2022-09-03 16:03:24 +0900
Processing by Api::V1::BooksController#search as HTML
  Parameters: {"keyword"=>"........."}
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=.........&country=JP
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88&country=JP
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=%E3%83%86%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88&country=JP
#<Net::HTTP:0x00007fd7a0119e58>
#<Net::HTTP::Get:0x00007fd7a0119930>
#<Net::HTTPOK:0x00007fd7a0125550>
200
OK
Completed 200 OK in 692ms (Views: 0.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 4250)
```

#### 該当のソースコード

models/google_book.rb

```
require 'google_books_api'

class GoogleBook
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  
  attribute :google_books_api_id, :string
  attribute :authors
  attribute :image, :string
  attribute :published_at, :date
  attribute :title, :string
  attribute :publisher, :string
  
  
  validates :google_books_api_id, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true
  
  class << self
  #lib以下に作成したモジュールを使用する
  include GoogleBooksApi
  
    def new_from_item(item)
      @item = item
      @volume_info = @item['volumeInfo']
      new(
        google_books_api_id: @item['id'],
        authors: @volume_info['authors'],
        image: image_url,
        published_at: @volume_info['publishedDate'],
        title: @volume_info['title'],
        publisher: @volume_info['publisher'],
      )
    end
  
    def new_from_id(google_books_api_id)
      url = url_of_creating_from_id(google_books_api_id)
      item = get_json_from_url(url)
      new_from_item(item)
    end
 

#エラー発生個所↓
#以下のメソッドをコントローラーで使用します。
#フロントエンドからパラメーターとして送られてくる「keyword」を
#引数に取っています。

    def search(keyword)
      #フロントエンドからのリクエストをuriに変換
      #url_of_searching_from_keywordメソッドは以下のmoduleで定義
      url = url_of_searching_from_keyword(keyword)
      #ログに書き込み
      Rails.logger.debug(url)

      #urlをエンコード
      enc = Addressable::URI.encode(url)
      #ログに書き込み
      Rails.logger.debug(enc)

      #uriに変換
      uri = URI.parse(enc)
      #ログに書き込み
      Rails.logger.debug(uri)
      
      #hostとポート番号をターミナルに出力
      #puts uri.host => www.googleapis.com
      #puts uri.port => 443

      require 'net/https'
      http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
      Rails.logger.debug(http)
      http.use_ssl = true
      http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

　　
      request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
      ×#getリクエストが為されているかをlogに書き込む
      訂正#getリクエストするための objectが作られているかをlogに書き込む
      Rails.logger.debug(request)
　　
　　#↓ここがおかしい(レスポンスが返ってこない)
      response = http.request(request)
　　#↑ここまでの処理を機能させたい
```

lib/google_books_api.rb

```
module GoogleBooksApi
  
  def url_of_searching_from_keyword(keyword)
    "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=#{keyword}&country=JP"
  end
```

#### 試したこと

①httpからhttps通信に
当初
response ＝ Net::HTTP.get(uri)
というコードを使用していましたが、これを上記modelの通りssl化しました。

②Rails.logger.debugによるデバッグで問題発生箇所を特定

コードを分解し、Rails.logger.debugでどこまで処理が実行されているか確認
したところ
Production.logのlogで
Net::HTTP::Get:0x00007f7e4af86658
というログを発見したため、RailsからGoogle Books Apiへのgetリクエスト自体は送られていると思われます。

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

現在もエラーの原因を調査中ですが、他の方の知恵や対処法(デバック方法)を知りたくて質問させていただきました。
どうか、皆様の力を貸してください。
足りない情報やご意見がありましたら、コメントを頂けると助かります！

Ruby 3.0.2
Rails 6.1.6

Comment: この EC2 インスタンスからインターネットに繋がっていますか？　インフラ側の問題なのか Ruby 側の問題なのか API 側の問題なのか切り分けたいです。タイムアウトなのでインフラ側のネットワーク設定を疑っています。EC2 インスタンス上から手で curl すると成功しますか？　またこの API ではないエンドポイントへのリクエストだとどうでしょうか。

Comment: 念のため
pingで確認したところ、nekketsuuuさんが仰っているようにRailsが入っているEc2コンテナがインターネットと繋がっていない事を疑っています。現在セキュリティ等の設定を見直している最中です。

Comment: 試行錯誤中の情報も大事ですが、質問はあくまで「質問」の体裁を保ってください。解決に至った情報は「回答」として投稿しましょう。

Comment: 失礼しました。修正しましたが、不備がありましたらコメントいただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

公式の設定例に従ってRails側のネットワークモードを「awsvpc」にしておりましたが、
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonECS/latest/bestpracticesguide/networking-outbound.html
↑の記事によればawsvpcはインターネットゲートウェイが使えない事が分かりました。
[image: イメージ説明]
その為、Rails側のタスク定義でネットワークモードを以下のとおり「bridge」で作り直しました。
[image: イメージ説明]
結果としてはawsのコンソールにおいて「portが重複しているため、サービスを作成できない」旨のエラーメッセージが発生しサービスを作成できませんでした。
いくつか記事を見たところ
https://aws.amazon.com/jp/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dynamic-port-mapping-ecs/
を発見し、動的ポートマッピングというものを行えば良いのではないか？と気づきました。
[image: イメージ説明]
そして、記事に則りネットワーク周り等を作り直しました。
作り直したものは
●アプリケーションロードバランサー(バックエンド用)
●ターゲットグループ(バックエンド用)
●Rails側のタスク定義
●Rails側のサービス
です。
そして、ロードバランサーを作り直したため、Route53を再設定しました(Aレコード)。
その後、以下によればRails側のセキュリティグループで上記ロードバランサーをインバウンドルールに追加する必要がある事が分かり、以下に沿ってRails側のセキュリティグループのインバウンドルールを編集しました。
[image: イメージ説明]
セキュリティを全てを見せる事は出来ないので、抜粋しますが以下の様になります。
[image: イメージ説明]
以上の作業を行い、
Rails側の本番用のurlをブラウザに入力し、アクセスしたところ、head200を返すだけのヘルスチェック用アクションにブラウザからアクセスできるようになりました(真白な画面が表示されます)。
また、クラスターにssh接続をした後、Rails側のコンテナにdocker exec で侵入し、外部（GoogleApi）に向けてpingとcurlコマンドを打ったところ、無事レスポンスが返ってくる事を確認しました。
しかし、次は以前ネットワークモードをawsvpcにした状態で正常に作動していたRdsとの接続において、別のエラーが発生し、NuxtとRailsの疎通が不可能になりました。
幾つか記事を読んだところ、以下の記事を発見し、
https://qiita.com/fkana/items/a4b3c4d5d8ca27cd20ec
https://zatoima.github.io/aws-ec2-psql-install.html
Rails側のセキュリティが怪しい、と気づきました。
その後、Rails側のセキュリティグループに以下のインバウンドルールを設定しました。
[image: イメージ説明]
その結果、表題の
「Net::HTTPでNet::OpenTimeout (execution expired)に対処したい」
という目的が達成されました。
ただし、私自身awsの設定やセキュリティの知見はありません。
上記の画像はアクセスの許容範囲が広い設定であるため、セキュリティの問題を孕んでおり、あくまで暫定的な処置になると思われます(アクセスの範囲を絞る必要がある？)。

Comment: まとめると、「セキュリティやネットワークの設定が誤っていてインターネットやサービス間の通信ができていなかったが、直したらできるようになった。」という感じでしょうか。 // 回答のスクリーンショットでは、PostgreSQLに全ての送信元からのリクエストを許可しているようですが、これで大丈夫でしょうか……？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。その通りです。現状は表題のエラーが無くなりアプリケーションが「動く」状態になっただけなので修正する必要があります・・・。

Comment: 私のアプリケーションはRails、Postgres(Rds)、Nuxt.Jsそれぞれにセキュリティグループを設定しています。RailsとNuxt.jsは個別のalb経由でネットワーク通信を行っており、上記の設定ですとRailsが稼働しているEC2コンテナの5432番ポートを全開放している状態だと認識しています。表題の質問とは逸れるので書いて良いものか分からないのですが、このセキュリティの設定をどのように修正するかについては調査中です。